# Updating Multiple records using Linq Lambda in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a `ThresholdTable` table with two columns  `ID varchar(max)` and `Value varchar(max)`

```
ID |  Value
----------------
1  |  0701224225
2  |  0701224012
```

I want to update this to

```
ID |  Value
----------------
1  |  105394
2  |  105595
```

How I can achieve through C#, Linq, Lambda expression.

I am doing this way,

```
private const string ThresholdValue1 = "1";

private const string ThresholdValue2 = "2";

var Setting = this.context.ThresholdTable.Where(p => p.ID.Equals(ThresholdValue1) || p.ID.Equals(ThresholdValue2));
foreach (var s in Setting)
{
    if (s.ID.Equals(ThresholdValue1))
    {
        s.Value = "105394";
    }
    else if (s.ID.Equals(ThresholdValue2))
    {
        s.Value = 105595;
    }
    this.context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Please suggest me some better way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please put a bit more effort into formatting the code in your posts in future - it makes a big difference to readability. Next, it's not really clear what you're asking for... what "better" are you looking for? (It sounds like you should be saving the changes *after* the loop, admittedly... and you seem to be setting the value to a string in one situation and an integer in the other, which is odd to say the least.)

Comment: Honestly, the only thing i'd change is move the .SaveChanges() out of the loop so you get one dump to db vs many.

Comment: Simply I want this in LINQ, GO UPDATE ThresholdTable SET Value = 105394 WHERE ID = 1  GO
UPDATE ThresholdTable SET Value = 105595 WHERE ID = 2

Comment: What you want to do is not possible with LINQ. LINQ is only for reading, not for updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Linq` is for querying data, not for updating them.

Now, for a better alternative of your code, if you many values to update, you can put your desired values in a `Dictionary` and update your values while looping through them like

```
var valuesToPopulate = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
    { "1", "105394" }, 
    { "2", "105595" } 
};

foreach (var threashold in this.context.ThresholdTable)
{
    var valueToPopulate = valuesToPopulate.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key.Equals(threashold.ID.Equals));
    if (!valueToPopulate.Equals(new KeyValuePair<string, string>()))
        threashold.Value = valueToPopulate.Value;
}
this.context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Iterating over `ThresholdTable` is a very, very bad idea. What if there are millions of rows in the table? Every single one will be loaded!

Comment: @Abbondanza in this specific example op has shown two rows. In general, for any large data iterating is bad idea. But, Linq `Where` will also do a `foreach` on any data.

Comment: Sorry, but that is absolutely not correct. `Where()` takes an `Expression<>` that will be translated to a SQL query. This query will only load the two rows in question from the database. A `foreach` cannot be translated to SQL and thus will materialize _every_ row regardless of whether the loop body changes a loaded row or not. If you don't believe me then try it for yourself.

Comment: @Abbondanza Ah, my bad. I guess we are arguing on the wrong thing. I meant, for in-memory objects, `Where` does a `foreach`only. Yes, you are correct on the query evaluation part. The main point of the original answer was to use a dictionary to hold values to be updated, rather than an infinite if-else chain (in case there are lot of values to be updated). Missed the looping-on-db-rows part.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void updateMultiple()
{
    var ls = new int[] { 2, 3, 4 };
    var name = "xyz";
    using (var db = new SomeDatabaseContext())
    {
        var some = db.SomeTable.Where(x => ls.Contains(x.friendid)).ToList();
        some.ForEach(a =>
                        {
                            a.status = true;
                            a.name = name;
                        }
                    );
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Try to abstract the concrete IDs and threshold values into a structure instead of handling them separately with `if` and `||`. You could use an array, a list or - since you have ID/value combinations - a dictionary:

```
var newThresholds = new Dictionary<string, string>
    { 
        { "1", "105394" }, 
        { "2", "105595" } 
    };

var thresholdsToUpdate = this.context
    .ThresholdTable
    .Where(t => newThresholds.Keys.Contains(t.ID));

foreach (var threshold in thresholdsToUpdate)
{
    threshold.Value = newThresholds[threshold.ID];
}

this.context.SaveChanges();
```

However, LINQ is a query interface - you can only use it to *read* data, not to *update* it. Hence, you can load the correct rows with a LINQ query, but have to update them outside the query in a regular `foreach` loop.