# update 2 datatable using linq in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two datatables with same identity columns. I want to update two columns value in one table with other two columns value in another table. For example:

These are the two tables:

Table1:

```
  ID    Area Code   Name    Quantity    Amount
 ---   ----------  ------   --------   --------
  1        AA       A11         0         0
  2        BB       B11         0         0
  3        CC       C11         0         0
```

Table2:

```
  ID    Area Code    Quantity    Amount
 ---   --------      -------    --------
  1        AA          3          150
  2        BB          5          250
  3        CC          7          350
```

My desired datatable should like this:

DesiredTable:

```
  ID    Area Code   Name    Quantity    Amount
 ---   ----------  ------   --------   --------
  1        AA       A11         3         150
  2        BB       B11         5         250
  3        CC       C11         7         350
```

The join keys are ID and Area Code, I want to update column Quantity and Amount.
How to achieve this result with LINQ in vb.net?

Here is the code I have so far...

```
  Dim qry As IEnumerable = 
 (From dr In dt1.AsEnumerable _
 From dr2 In dt2.AsEnumerable _
 Where dr.Field(Of String)("ID") = dr2.Field(Of String)("ID") And _
       dr.Field(Of String)("AreaCode") = dr2.Field(Of String)("AreaCode")  
 Select New With {.ID = dr.Field(Of String)("ID"), _
            .AreaCode = dr.Field(Of String)("AreaCode"), _
            .Name     = dr.Field(Of String)("Name"), _
            .Quantity = dr2.Field(Of String)("Quantity"), _
            .Amount   = dr2.Field(Of String)("Amount")}).ToList()
```

Is this code work? and the next step, I need to insert that to my table at database. how can I do it vb.net?

I know it should be simple, so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132717/updating-multiple-records-using-linq-lambda-in-c-sharp) SO question.

Comment: Thanks fyi,I'm new in Linq, I need to update 2 column. the answer only for 1 column

Comment: The answer says: "Linq is for querying data, not for updating them." If it's not for updating 1 column, then it's not for updating 2 columns, too...

Comment: I want to join this two tables and then store it into one temporary table, which as shown as table no 3 above. Is it possible to do this in Linq? I also want to implement this in VB.Net as right now I'm trying to convert my SQL based query into Linq